# Listar dados agrupados e filtrados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Estou realizando uma consulta no PUBS, o banco que é utilizado nos tutoriais da MSDN para o SQL Server, e não consigo achar um jeito de fazê-la.

As duas tabelas que utilizo são a **publishers** e a **titles** que possuem as informações dos livros publicados e suas respectivas editoras.

Basicamente, quero uma consulta que liste as editoras que editaram pelo menos 5 livros.

Pensei em fazer uma consulta condicional do SQL Server (IF...ELSE), mas não sei ainda como vou elaborar a expressão condicional!

Realizei uma consulta para mostrar os id's das editoras e a quantidade de publicações realizadas por cada uma, aqui está o código:

```
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t.title_id)
    FROM titles t
    INNER JOIN publishers p ON t.pub_id = p.pub_id
    GROUP BY p.pub_id
```

Não sei se existe algum meio de setar uma variável com os valores retornados pelo `COUNT` e depois atribuí-la a uma expressão condicional (`@Variable > 5`, no caso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cláusula [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180199.aspx) para retornar as editoras com mais de `n` títulos:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.title_id)
FROM titles t
INNER JOIN publishers p ON t.pub_id = p.pub_id
GROUP BY p.pub_id
HAVING COUNT(t.pub_id) > 5
```

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado!

Comment: @user3648815 Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Se a resposta lhe ajudou, clique à esquerda da mesma para aceitá-la como a reposta certa. Caso tenha dúvidas, consulte nossa [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).